# Запрос с импользованием GROUP BY только по первому символу

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Делаю запрос к таблице, в которой имена:

```
// запрос
$zapros1001 = mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `table` GROUP BY `field`",$db);

// поле в таблице id,field содержит
1 Аня
2 Маша
3 Марина
4 Саша
5 Саша
6 Слава
7 Яна
```

Собственно, в конкретно этом случае получится 6 записей (1,2,3,4,6,7), т.к. 'саша' 2 раза. Можно ли сгруппировать только по первому символу? (или только по второму) Что бы в итоге получились уникальные А,М,С,Я (1,2,4,7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно:

```
select min(id), LEFT(field,1)
from `table`
group by LEFT(field,1)
```

Comment: все элементарно оказалось ) я думал там какой то перебор нужно после запроса делать

Comment: для второго символа `left(field,1)` меняем на `substring(field,2,1)`